# How is p-value performing as a measure of association?

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, cramers-v

It's known that Cramér's V (Chisq adjusted for table dimension and sample size) is a good measure of strength association.

But what about the p-value? P-value (as a probability of the numbers we have happened given there is no association) is also less affected by table dimension and sample size and can also reflect the strength of association.

What are the biggest flaws of "p-values as measures"? Do you guys have any practical insights into this?

Comment: Lots of questions raised here directly or indirectly. I've  seen Cramér's measure mentioned in some introductory texts and ignored by many more; its main usefulness seems to be in giving people a correlation-type measure which many researchers feel they want or need, but beyond indicating, some times, that there is a relationship that you should try to model, I don't know that it's a good measure. The fact that it adjusts for sample size and table dimensions in a way isn't necessarily a virtue.

Comment: The main point here is that P-value measures significance, not strength of association; its strong dependence on sample size is a large part of its rationale. This is clearer for e.g. correlations, regressions, t-tests than it is for low-dimensional cross-classifications where amount of information is encoded by number of degrees of freedom as well as sample size.